Reduce etendue by aperture
Lets look at a light source of area $S$ where each point on this surface emits light into a light cone with max. angle of $\alpha$. Then the etendue is -as far as I understood it- defined by $\epsilon = S \pi \sin^2(\alpha)$.
If I put an aperture close to the light source, I reduce the emitting area while not changing the max. angle. Looking at the formula, I would argue that I reduced the etendue.
Since I got different answers whether I really reduced the etendue, maybe there are different correct answers with regard to different definitions of etendue, e.g. infinitesimal vs. "makroskopic" etendue; or the etendue of the light source (my emitting area) vs. the etendue of the optical system (here just my aperture)?

You really did reduce etendue. That is not a problem, because you also did not conserve optical power. The aperture absorbs optical power so that there is less power on the post-aperture side compared to the pre-aperture side. You are guaranteed that etendue will never decrease in any optical system that conserves optical power. This system does not, so there is no such guarantee.

Thanks a lot! Can you recomment literature which describes the conditions under which the etendue is preserved / decreases / increases? Maybe even with a derivation?

@Matthiasho you can start just with the wikipedia entry on entendue: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue it includes information about when it increases and when it is guaranteed not to decrease as well as a derivation for refraction
